# Trying to add new elements to a list in a loop results in only the last element

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to add elements in a list in order to identify the max float of that list. But it only appends the latest element.

```
mylist= [[coffee, 1, 3], [milk,2,5], [butter, 6,4]]

for items in mylist:

    value = float(items[2]) * (float(items[1]))
    values = []
    values.append(value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try putting your `values = []` outside the loop. You are resetting the list on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension, something like this:

```py
org_lst = [['coffee', 1, 3], ['milk',2,5], ['butter', 6,4]]
lst = [x[1]*x[2] for x in org_lst]
print(lst)
```